# XAMARIN the call is ambiguous between the following methods

Tags: mono, xamarin

How can i fix this problem, I have tried everything but always the same error:

I am using this API: https://github.com/xamarin/google-apis

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to explicit call to the extension:

```
        var attribute = 
         Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.
             GetCustomAttribute<Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute>
                 (property);
```